# Implement HD Walet Full Node

Tags: wallet, bip32-hd-wallets

I have set up a full node on my server. Now, I want to make use of HD wallet methods?

How I generate an address for admin - Master address

How I generate addresses for customers - Child address

When I receive the deposit on child address, how it can be viewed on Master Address?

Do I need to transfer to the master address?

As I want to move all amount to my Cold wallet address so to do so I need to have a balance on my master address?

Please help

Comment: you should add some more information. which software are you running? have you read the the documentation to this software? And as you have many questions you should consider splitting them to single requests so it can beanswered individually and may help people with the exact same question.

Comment: I downloaded latest version of bitcoin-core from here https://bitcoin.org/en/download
Yes i have gone through the RPC command https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#rpcs

As i am very new to this, i need help in setting up HD wallet.
How I generate an address for admin - Master address?
How I generate addresses for customers - Child address?
When I receive the deposit on child address, how it can be viewed on Master Address? 
Do I need to transfer to the master address? 
As I want to move all amount to my Cold wallet address so to do I need to have a balance on my master address?

Comment: as already told, it seems you mix up some topics and put several questions under one topic. the goal of this page is to produce a knowledge base to find answers on special questions which is impossible if we answer your 5 questions in one post.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not following you. All questions are related to the HD wallet only? Do u want me to post a separate question for each? Please suggest?

Comment: some of your questions are related to hd wallets some related to general handling, some to security aspects. but at all, these are 5 seperate questions... and most basic ones discussed several times here and elsewhere. make sure you`ve done basic research before please. Your questions look like you do not have a basic understanding of (hd) wallets and address generation. And most of your questions are related to a single api call - if you have questions to one, here you´ll get the answer, but don´t expect us to do the research for you.

Comment: Hi @Michael I already running a private node and have implemented all API in several of my projects. But I am not aware of the HD wallet, the only thing I know is a theory that addresses are generated from master address and can be recovered from master seed.I need help to get the methods that I can use to implement an HD wallet. If there is any documentation available let me know.My friend i am not expecting research from you, just need a guide/help which i can follow for my implementation.

Comment: realy? no information about HD wallets in the whole internet? [https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#type-2-hierarchical-deterministic-hd-wallets](https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#type-2-hierarchical-deterministic-hd-wallets) [https://bitcoin.org/en/wallets-guide#wallet-programs](https://bitcoin.org/en/wallets-guide#wallet-programs) [https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0032.mediawiki) ...

Comment: @Michael these I have already looked at. Anyways Thanks for your help.